# Django Signal request_finished get user instanse

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

I try to understand Signals in Django. I am creating project for DRF.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.core.signals import request_finished
```

For this Signal I can catch user

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def last_user_login(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    print('User **{}** logged in'.format(user))
```

And I want to catch user for this signal, but it's impossible as I understood.

```
@receiver(request_finished)
def last_user_request(sender, **kwargs):
    print('User made request')
```

My target: catch last user request and write this data to db.

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) to achieve this:

**middleware.py:**

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
   def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.
    
    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
    
        response = self.get_response(request)
    
        print(response.status_code)
        print(request.user.username)
        # Add user data in db....
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.POST)
    
        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.
    
        return response
```

**settings.py:**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',    
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     
    'myproject.middleware.SimpleMiddleware',
    
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`request_finished` signal only has information about its sender class, as you can see in `HttpResponseBase` class where its sent:

```
signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
```

In order to accomplish what you want, you could look into writing a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware), where you will have access to the `request` object and thus to `User` as well. Think it through if you really want to write to the db there, it might be slow.